# count the occurrences of value in column 1 for each string in column 2 using awk

Tags: unix, awk

I have a large file with 7 columns, I would like to compare 2 columns, col 1 and col 7

```
 chr_locations(col 1)        gene_name(col 7)
chr1:66997989-67000678        geneA
chr1:66997824-67000456        geneA
chr2:33544389-33548489        geneB
chr2:33546285-33547055        geneB
chr2:44567890-44568980        geneB
```

I would like to count the occurrences of chromosomal locations for a given gene:

```
chr1:66997989-67000678    geneA     2
chr1:66997824-67000456    geneA     2
chr2:33544389-33548489    geneB     3
chr2:33546285-33547055    geneB     3
chr2:44567890-44568980    geneB     3
```

I am sure there is an easier way to do this in awk than writing a script in python, can any of you help? Thanks.

Comment: *I am sure there is an easier way to do this in awk than writing a script in python*. *Easier* means you have already a version in Python which is *not* easy?. Can you show that?. Please also check this page which helps you how to format your question properly: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: what is column 1 contribution to the counts?

Comment: Can you combine `cut` for columns 1 and 7, `sort` and `uniq -c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with both languages it is easy (any language really).... all depends on your knowledge

**awk**

```
awk '{
    count[$7]++; 
    memory_1[NR] = $1; 
    memory_7[NR] = $7;
} 
END{
    for(i=1; i<=NR; ++i) print memory_1[i] OFS memory_7[i] OFS count[memory_7[i]]
}' file
```

**python**

```
records = [line.split() for line in open("file").readlines()]
from collections import Counter
count = Counter(r[6] for r in records)
print "\n".join("\t".join((r[0], r[6], str(count[r[6]]))) for r in records)
```

you get:

```
chr1:66997989-67000678  geneA   2
chr1:66997824-67000456  geneA   2
chr2:33544389-33548489  geneB   3
chr2:33546285-33547055  geneB   3
chr2:44567890-44568980  geneB   3
```

Comment: You should mention that awk solution requires GNU awk4.0 or later for true multi-dimensional arrays. Or you could use the old pseudo-multi-dimensional array syntax (e.g. `memory[NR,1]`) since you're not doing anything that requires true m-d arrays.

Comment: Yeah, it can be hard to remember. There's a pretty extensive list at http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#POSIX_002fGNU and http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Feature-History (you need to combine both pages to get the full list) but some of the things that were gawk-only when introduced are now adopted by POSIX (e.g. `delete array`) so that second reference isn't exactly the gawk-only stuff, it's the stuff that at least at one time was gawk-only (most of it still is though).

Answer (score 2):

You need an array to keep the count, and use an array key constructed with your 2 columns

```
awk '
    {count[$1 OFS $7]++} 
    END {for (key in count) print key, count[key]}
' file | sort
```

You need to provide some actual data if you expect us to test our answers.